# How to return the last name to the front and then follow by the initial of the first name using Python?

Tags: python

Write function lastF() that takes as input a string of the form 'FirstName LastName'
and returns a string of the form 'LastName, F.'. (Only the initial should be output for
the first name.)

```
>>> lastF('John Locke')
>>>'Locke, J.'
```

here is my code:

```
def LastF(n):
for i in n:
    return n[-1]+', '+n[0][0]+'.'
```

I have looked others similar questions and I cannot catch it. By far I have yet to learn about the split(), is there any other way can solve this question?

Comment: How are you expected to handle those with either two first names or two last names? i.e "Norma Jean Mortenson" or "John Moore Williams"

Comment: @Sayse I think the question is only asking for a program that deals with one first name and one last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use `split` you have to do the splitting manually. Find the space character and take everything after it as the last name.

```
def lastF(name):
    index = name.index(' ')
    last_name = name[index+1:]
    first_character = name[0]
    return f'{last_name}, {first_character}'

print(lastF('John Locke'))
```

The result is `Locke, J`.

---

The f-string in `return f'{last_name}, {first_character}'` prevents ugly string concatenation as in `return last_name + ', ' + first_character`.

You could even compress everything in one line:

```
def lastF(name):
    return f'{name[name.index(" ")+1:]}, {name[0]}'
```

Comment: Hi may I ask what does the name[index+1:] mean? What is the function of the + ?

Comment: The space character is at the position `index`. We want to start one character later so we add one to the position and that's `index + 1`. Then we get a slice from the string `name` with `name[index+1:]` starting at `index+1` up to the end of the string. Should you be not familiar with slicing: That's a basic string operation and is explained in the tutorial in the chapter about [Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 2):

```py
def LastF(n):
    return(n.split(' ')[1] + ', ' + n.split(' ')[0][0] + '.')
print(LastF("John Locke"))
```

What it does: splits the string into pieces based on the whitespaces, takes the second part, adds comma, adds the second part's first letter (`n.split(' '),[0][0]`), and adds a `.`

Comment: is the splitting automatically split the string at the whitespace? Or do I have to mention it in the ()?

Comment: @Darren it is automatic even if you do not mention it as it is the default argument of `.split()`

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```py
def lastF(text):
    splitted = text.split()
    return splitted[-1] + ", " + text[0] + "."
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def LastF(n):
    parts = n.split(' ') #split your input by whitespace
    return(parts[1] + ', ' + n[0] + '.') #returns the second element of the split and concatenates first letter of the input text
print(LastF("John Locke"))
```